MAUI - Saber que switch he pulsado dentro de un grid en tiempo de ejecucion
Creo un switch dentro de un grid en tiempo de ejecución y segun los datos me genera diferentes lineas de grid con diferentes switch.
grid.Add(new Switch {Margin = new Thickness(0, 10),Background = Colors.White,ThumbColor = colors.Red,IsToggled = false,}, 6, 0);

stack1 .Children.Add(grid);

¿Como puedo saber de los switch que se han creado en las diferentes lineas, cual he pulsado?
Muchas Gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! no tiene asociado ni un evento ni nada?
